# SQL syntax error or server error?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

Hey guys I am new to the whole database scene and trying to perform a relatively simple task but apparently I am doing something wrong. Every time I try to execute this statement I get a 1064 error telling me either my syntax is wrong or the server version is too old. the SQL server version is 5.1.x and I am running PHP5.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cut_log` (`driver`, `date1`, `time`, `cut`, `flood`, `notes`) VALUES ($driver, $date, $time, $cut, $flood, $notes)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "" . $mysqli->errno . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: You need to quote `($driver, $date, $time, $cut, $flood, $notes)` do `('$driver', '$date', '$time', '$cut', '$flood', '$notes')`

Comment: You should echo out the query that gives the error. And you better use prepared statements with parameters to bind the input values to, to avoid sql injection and avoid escaping problems.

Comment: If you're going to forget quotes around strings in SQL statements, do yourself a favour and learn to use bind variables

Comment: You're also probably not checking for errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cut_log` (`driver`, `date1`, `time`, `cut`, `flood`, `notes`) VALUES ('$driver', '$date', '$time', '$cut', '$flood', '$notes')";
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't realize that you needed quotes for the values. However on all the other documentation and examples I have seen, they have also been binding the variables. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Like John said, the problem is that it's missing quotes.
What you should have done is [**prepare**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) the query to [**avoid SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) attacks:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cut_log` (`driver`, `date1`, `time`, `cut`, `flood`, `notes`) 
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $driver, $date, $time, $cut, $flood, $notes);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
      echo "success";
    } else {
      echo "" . $mysqli->errno . $mysqli->error;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Fred You always great with the details ! :D

Comment: Thanks guys! I tried running that as-is and although the query executed, it threw an error on run...there aren't any other variables that would account for the error. thoughts?
Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Users/Matt/path/to/zam/cut.php on line 21

Comment: @MattSanford I counted 6 fields, if any of them is an int type then change the `s` to `i`

Comment: @meda Four of the data types are VARCHAR, one is TIME the other is DATE. In order it would be VC-D-T-VC-VC-VC. I changed the bind params to siisss but still got the same error.

Comment: @MattSanford no so `ssssss` is correct because dates are strings, is it inserting everything correctly?

Comment: I cant see the error did you copy paste my code, there should be no quotes around the question mark